# How to add a tab to shop pages?

Tags: views, 8, commerce, navigation

I'm on Drupal 8 with Commerce 2.

I created a view page to display the list of products in the stores.

Here is the way of my sight :

/store/3/produits

Can not add a tab to shop pages.

I am desperate.

Can you explain why the "Edit" tab on the page is missing ?

[image]

**Here is my view, it is very simple :**

[image]

**Here is my page "Produits", there is no tab :**

[image]

Comment: Because you need a default stub tab first in order to add more tabs on to it.

Comment: So, create a default menu tab at boutiques/%/list, which is the same exact output as boutiques/%. Then, your Products tab should show.

Comment: @Kevin I do not understand how to do that. Can you give me an answer with an example ? Thank you

Comment: @Kevin Some screenshots

Comment: Those mentions do not work if I never had any interaction with the post ;) But as Kevin stated, you need to have a stub tabs first.

Comment: @ZenImagine It would be helpful if you upload views.view.YOUR_PRODUCTS.yml file here.

Comment: @drugan You must use this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242251/the-menu-tabs-show-an-error I can not delete this page because it is related to my second question.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** install [Commerce Multistore](https://github.com/drugan/commerce_multistore) module and have store/ID/edit, store/ID/products, user/ID/stores views tabs created by default for you

**UPDATE:** [Add store/ID/edit, store/ID/products, user/ID/stores views tabs](https://www.drupal.org/node/2880510)

Tabs can be automatically created for you by Views.

**WDTutorials** video: [Tabs With Views in Drupal 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpuRdzyK3jI)

You have to create a views' page having **/some-path**  which lists some entities (nodes, fields or products as in your question). Then you need to make it a **Default menu tab** (parent menu tab). So, if no any child tabs are present then the content for this tab will be displayed. It might be seen a bit confusing but you should choose **Already exists** option while creating this (newly created) menu tab. After that just create as many duplications of this page as you need and choose for each duplication a **Menu tab** option (child menu tab). Again, you might be confused which menu or menu entry to choose for children menu tabs. Actually, it does not matter a lot. For your view you may choose **Products** entry though **<Main navigation>** menu might be also a good choice. Do not ignore **weight** option assigning a proper value for each child tab. It helps to place tabs in the exact order you want. Leave **0** weight for the parent tab increasing it by 1 for each next tab.

Then, edit the path so it looks like **/some-path/child-1** and add a filter criteria for a child tab (page). In the video the filter criteria is a node's published/unpublished status and in your case it should be a store ID. The ID of a particular store might be found on the **/admin/commerce/stores** by hovering over a store's **Edit** tab.

See more on the relative drupal.org issue:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2880510#comment-12185171

Comment: Thank you, the tabs seem to work on I go into the ID path of the shop. On the other hand, it does not work with a contextual filter and a path with %

Comment: Here is the path to a shop "/store/3" to apply to all the shop, I created in my view a contextual filter with the ID and I put the "path / store/%/products". But nothing works as expected.

Comment: What really annoys me is that I manage to create tabs on the assembly of my site without any problem (even on the user and group pages), but on the pages of the shop it is a big big problem . Another thing, when you view a shop page there is no tab "Edit" is very weird.

Comment: On simplytest, try to create a shop with two or three products. Now on the page of your shop, create a list of the products of the current shop (a view with a contextual filter). The path should be / store / ID / products and the tabs "View; Edit; Products". Please tell me if you have succeeded, thank you.

Comment: Fairly speaking I am still the same as you learning Drupal 8 views. Now I've found some trick how to display  store/%/products. I am going to make a video if I don't find already existing somewhere else.  As for the no "Edit" option you should look for permissions on the view (view tab).

Comment: I look forward to seeing how you did it. Regarding the "Edit" tab, the shop page is not a view and the tab should have been created by default by the "Commerce" module. There is an "Edit" tab on the nodes and products, I did not create it. It is displayed by default.

Comment: Can you tell me the solution you found in your previous comment? For the "Edit" tab I do not understand what to do, because the "Edit" tab is not a view. Thank you

Comment: @ZenImagine  As I said earlier I want to give an answer (may be a video screencast or even a patch for drupalcommerce) which might be useful for many users. The issue of displaying products enabled for a particular store is quite generic one if you have a site with many sellers (marketplace). So, please wait a bit. I'll post the answer as soon as I find the most appropriate solution. The one which I have right now is just a workaround, not a real solution.